# PyCharm complains about unresolved reference for a variable injected through another module

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-import

I have the following files:

```
# b.py
from .a import A
class B(A):
    ...
```

.

```
# a.py
class A:
    def m(self):
        return B()
```

.

```
# __init__.py
from . import a
from .b import B
a.B = B
```

The three files above are in a package named `p`.

Everything works fine, except that in module `a`, PyCharm warns that `B` is an unresolved reference.

Question:

Is there any way to help PyCharm see what's going on and avoid the warning?

I can rewrite the import statements if it helps, but want to keep `A` and `B` classes in separate modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another way to mitigate this issue. Add the following fake imports to end of `a.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from .b import B
```

This way PyCharm stops complaining and even is able to do inspections about B and its methods.

Of-coarse the import is not actually done during the runtime because `a.py` is [not intended to be run as a script](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/__main__.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could define B:

```
# a.py
def B():
    assert False, "this needs to be overridden"

class A:
    def m(self):
        return B()
```

You can also tell pycharm to ignore the unresolved reference:

```
# a.py

class A:
    def m(self):
        # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
        return B()
```

Comment: Setting `B` to `None` causes another warning about `B` not being callable. But I didn't know about the `noinspection` directive, thanks!